# How to fetch html from url and display in div

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to fetch the body of the URL and display it in the DIV. I am not able to get the result that i want.

Here is my code.
index.js

```
fetch('https://github.com/')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(body => document.getElementById('embed-html').innerHTML);
```

html

```
<div id="embed-html"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, you cannot use fetch to send a request to a different domain.

If you really need to do this, you can try using jQuery and iFrames (read more at http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes).

Comment: can i fetch from server and send to client?

Comment: because when i console.log(body), it shows the HTML body of github. I just need to append it to the div to display properly